# Do pressure surge oscillations in a pipe decay even when there is no friction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

For t < 0, I have a steady uniform flow of a liquid in a pipe from a high pressure reservoir on the right to a low pressure reservoir on the left. At t=0, a valve on the left is instantaenously closed and the well known surge pressure oscillations (waterhammer) run up and down the pipe. At t= infinty, the flow in the pipe is zero and the pressure is constant and equal to that in the high pressure reservoir.

My question is : If the fluid had no viscosity, would the final state be the same as above or would the surge pressure oscillations continue forever undamped ?

Comment: Water hammer is a pulse of pressure. Sound is also a series of pressure pulses. Sound a long ways away gets fainter because sound spreads out and sound is absorbed. So are you asking about mechanisms of sound absorption? The only fluids with no viscosity are superfluids. Are you asking about sound absorption in superfluids?

Comment: @messer314 - I am asking a theoretical question here - If I solve the above problem with the Euler equations (which have no viscosity), do the pressure pulses (sound waves) decay ?